# Unable to check empty string in if condition using ionic2

Tags: typescript, ionic2

I'm Working on search form were i need to check whether city is empty or not. If it is empty then assign Bangalore to it other show the selected city. Here is my If condition

```
if(this.locations[0].city!="")
{
   var Dynamic = this.locations[0].city;
}
else
{
   Dynamic = "Bangalore";
}
```

But getting

> Runtime Error. cannot read property '0' of undefined.

I am new to Ionic 2.

Answer (score 1):

modify the IF condition like the below

```
 if(this.location!=undefined && this.location.length!=0 && this.locations[0].city!="")
    {
       var Dynamic = this.locations[0].city;
    }
    else
    {
       Dynamic = "Bangalore";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I might do this

```
var Dynamic = "Bangalore";
' first to are verifying they are defined
if(this.locations && this.locations[0] && this.locations[0].city && this.locations[0].city.length > 0)
{
  Dynamic = this.locations[0].city;
}
```

Comment: I think this will fail if `this.locations[0]` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a function called `checkNested` for checking the validity of a nested object and use it throughout your app. You can put that in a service.

Also, I think you should define `Dynamic` outside of the if statement for scoping reasons.

```
var Dynamic = "Bangalore";
if(this.locations &&  // Checking if this.locations is valid before indexing it
   this.checkNested(this.locations[0], "city") && 
   this.locations[0].city !="" ){
   Dynamic = this.locations[0].city;
}
```

`checkNested` function is defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2631198/1383356).